# ¿Como detecto todos los cambios en un input type de un formulario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas, tengo este formulario:

```js
  function balidatu(){
   var pas1 = $("#pass").val();
   var pas2 = $("#passC").val();
   if(pas1 != pas2){
    alert("Pasahitzak berdinak izan behar dira.");
    return(false);
   }else{
    return(true);
   }
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#pass").change(){
    $("#posta").val("JAJAJAJAJA");
   }
  });
```

```html
  <div id='page-wrap'>
 <span><a href='../HTML5/layout.html'>Atzera</a></span> <br><br>
 
 <h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>
    
 <div>
   <form id="galderenF" name="galderenF" method="post" action="signUp.php" onsubmit="return balidatu()">
    
    <label for="posta"><strong>Posta (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="email" name="posta" id="posta" placeholder="Zure posta"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}[0-9]{3}@ikasle\.ehu\.(eus|es)"  required/><br>
    
    <label for="deitura"><strong>Deitura (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="deitura" minlength="10" id="galdera" placeholder="Zure deitura" required/><br>
    
    <label for="nick"><strong>Nick (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="nick" id="erantzunZuzena" placeholder="Zure nick-a" required/><br>
    
    <label for="pasahitza" ><strong>Pasahitza (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="password" name="pasahitza" minlength = "6" id="pass" placeholder="Pasahitza" required/><br>
    
    <label for="pasEr" ><strong>Pasahitza Errepikatu (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="password" name="pasahitzaRep" minlength = "6" id="passC" placeholder="Pasahitza errepikatu" required/><br>
    
    <input class="botoia" type="submit" id="botoia1" value="Erregistratu" />
    <input class="botoia" type="reset" id="botoia2" value="Reset" />
    <div id="aster" ><strong> * | Nahitaezko hutsuneak </strong></div><br><br>
    
   </form>
    <div id = "ezkutatu1" style = 'display:block'>Posta egiaztatzen...  </div>
    <div id = "erakutsiEgiaBada1" style = 'display:none'> Posta onargarria da </div> 
    <div id = "erakutsiGezurraBada2" style = 'display:none'> Posta existitzen da WSan </div> 
    
    <div id = "ezkutatu2" style = 'display:block'> Pasahitza egiaztatzen... </div>
    <div id = "erakutsiEgiaBada2" style = 'display:none'> Pasahitza onargarria da </div>
    <div id = "erakutsiGezurraBada2" style = 'display:none'> Pasahitza ez da onargarria da </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se cambie un carácter en Pasahitza (contraseña) lea un fichero (lo cual implementaré más tarde cuando sepa como detectar estos cambios). 
 He probado la funcion change() de jQuery pero no funciona, no sé si es porque change() no vale para lo que quiero o si algo está mal.
Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sobre tu inquietud es mejor usar con jquery on, ya que el .click y .change van quedando descontinuados, por tanto si requieres generar un listener seria de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#tuID").on("change",function(){
  // aqui va el codigo que requieres hacer cuando se genere algun cambio....
});
```

es importante generar dentro del ready este comportamiento es decir quedaria algo asi:

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $("#tuID").on("change",function(){
  // aqui va el codigo que requieres hacer cuando se genere algun cambio....
  });
});
```

la idea es que el input que le haces el listener va a estar a la escucha de los cambios que le hagas; Tambien es importante comtemplar la posibilidad que generes los input dinamicamente con append, por tanto si algun input lo haces asi ten presente que el listener se armaria de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).on("change","#tuID",function(){
   // aqui va tu codigo cuando generas un input dinamico y que se le pueda
   // incluir un listener.
});
```

Saludos, espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Ha funcionado, es lo que quería gracias. Marcaré tu respuesta en 10 minutos.